# Indirect parameter expansion of an array argument in Bash

Tags: bash

How can one expand a parameter when the parameter is an array?

If the parameter is a simple variable, we can do an indirection using an exclamation point.

```
single_fruit()
{
    if [ "$#" != 1 ]; then exit 1; fi
    echo ${!1}
}

MYVAR=Persimmon
single_fruit MYVAR
```

I'd like to do the same on an array parameter. Rather than iterate over the elements of an array directly:

```
FRUIT=(Papaya Pineapple)
for f in ${FRUIT[@]}
do
    echo ${f}
done
```

I'd like to iterate within a function:

```
multi_fruit()
{
    if [ "$#" != 1 ]; then exit 1; fi
    PARAMETER=${1}
    for i in ${!PARAMETER[@]}
    do
        echo ${i}
    done
}

MOREFRUITS=(Mango Melon)
multi_fruit MOREFRUITS
```

Can you make this last function iterate over the array elements?

Comment: Three useful and distinct solutions are given below. I accepted the one that requires the simplest function call and up-voted the other two.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it, but in an unexpected way: the placeholder var needs to include the array index:

```
multi_fruit() { 
    (( $# != 1 )) && return 1
    tmp="${1}[@]"
    for i in "${!tmp}"; do
        echo "$i"
    done
}
```

Also, it's a bad idea to use only uppercase variable names. One day you'll accidentally overwrite PATH and wonder why your script is broken. Leave uppercase vars to the system.

Also note that putting braces around the variable is not the same as double quotes. For example, consider:

```
var="one two three"
printf "%s\n" ${var}
printf "%s\n" "$var"
```

Comment: Writing "${1}[@]" means that we simply append the literal [@]. Subsequently, the expansion occurs on the array name, while the literal [@] is carried on. Is this what's happening?

Comment: Yes that's right. Unfortunately the bash developers overloaded `${!...` -- when applied to an array, that gives you the array *indices*: `declare -A x=([foo]=bar [baz]=qux); echo ${!x[@]}` outputs `foo baz` (in some order) -- with a "scalar" variable, it performs the indirection: hence `${!tmp}`

Answer (score 2):

It is not straight forward to pass around arrays in BASH. In fact arrays aren't even exported to sub shells. To pass array variable to a function you need to use "ARRAY[@]" syntax and then reconstruct the array inside the function using variable indirection operator.

Consider this script:

```
multi_fruit() {
    if [ "$#" != 1 ]; then exit 1; fi
    # array reconstructions
    arr=("${!1}")
    for i in ${arr[@]}
    do
        echo ${i}
    done
}

MOREFRUITS=(Mango Melon)
multi_fruit "MOREFRUITS[@]"
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Mango
Melon
```

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
multi_fruit()
{
    if [ $# -lt 1 ]; then exit 1; fi
    for i in "$@"
    do
        echo ${i}
    done
}

MOREFRUITS=(Mango Melon)
multi_fruit "${MOREFRUITS[@]}"
```

Comment: Interesting.. I'm still trying to parse what the bash man page says about the $@ special parameter.

Comment: Unquoted, `$@` is identical to `$*`. It is almost always the special quoted behavior that leads you to use `$@`, so you should always use quotes: `"$@"`. When not quoting it, use `$*` to provide a clue that you intentionally left it unquoted.

Answer (score 0):

why not using "declare -n"?...

```
multi_fruit() {
declare array_type array_values i
[[ ${1} ]] &&
    read _ array_type array_values < <(declare -p "$1") &&
    [[ ${array_type:0:2} == "-a" ]] &&
    declare -n array2use=$1 && # printf "%s\n" "${array2use[@]}"
    for i in "${!array2use[@]}"; do
        echo "${array2use[$i]}"
    done
}
```

(I know this post is older - but someone might find this using google and that someone might find this useful - or just more complete :) )